# Avahi error on startup

Tags: networking, avahi

Each time I start up, I get a blue popup-like blue window with an exclamation mark giving me what looks like an error message. It does not stay long enough for me to write it down.

It says something like:

```
Avahi does not support ".local".. something about network?
```

But a lot more text... I deduced the name "avahi" from trying tab-completion in a terminal. ;) It has something to do with some network or other. I have cable internet, and also a wireless network adapter that is switched off.

Is this something to be concerned about? I am running an 11.04 Ubuntu inside a WinXP, on a USB-drive.